# How to change source code chromium for update extensions from own server?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chromium

We are developing a chromium based browser for smm specialists. Also, we have an extension that needs to be installed and updated through our server.

In manifest extension I added update url: 

`"update_url": "https://super-smm.com/store/extensions/ciinbcgllnekeikkpgmchahilfcihfhp.xml"`

On the server, I upload file ciinbcgllnekeikkpgmchahilfcihfhp.xml with such content:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<gupdate xmlns='http://www.google.com/update2/response' protocol='2.0'>
    <app appid='ciinbcgllnekeikkpgmchahilfcihfhp'>
        <updatecheck codebase='https://super-smm.com/store/extensions/SuperSMM-0.18.18.crx'version='0.18.18' />
    </app>
</gupdate>
```

But this doesn't work! The extension does not update.
What should I change in Chromium source code for the extensions updating from own server?

Comment: You can try poking https://cs.chromium.org

Answer (score 0):

There is a missed space in your XML, right before `version=`. 
It should be:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<gupdate xmlns='http://www.google.com/update2/response' protocol='2.0'>
    <app appid='ciinbcgllnekeikkpgmchahilfcihfhp'>
        <updatecheck codebase='https://super-smm.com/store/extensions/SuperSMM-0.18.18.crx' version='0.18.18'/>
    </app>
</gupdate>
```

Be sure, that you are making update to the newer version because extensions will not update to the same or a previous version.